# Who is the first villain to use kryptonite against Superman and how did they know it was his one weakness?

Tags: dc, superman

I'm going to assume it's [Lex](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Lex_Luthor) or maybe [Metallo](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Lex_Luthor)?

But do we know for sure, who was the first villain to use kryptonite against Superman?

Where did they obtain it and how did they know / discover it was his one weakness?

I'm hoping all these details are covered in the same story.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrvRfBiWaMk

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptonite

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first use (in any media) was in the radio play "[The Scarlet Widow](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Scarlet_Widow)" from 1943. The eponymous villainess steals kryptonite from the Metropolis Museum and uses it to build a cage for Superman, incapacitating him for several episodes.

Interestingly, the plot device was apparently intended to give the Superman voice actor (Bud Collyer) [a few days holiday](http://superman.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonite) as his character was restricted to pre-recorded grunts and screams.

The first use in any comic serial was from Superman #61 ("[Superman Returns to Krypton](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_61)"). Superman fights a self-styled Swami whose kryptonite turban-stone causes Superman to become weakened. This edition is also famous for being the first time that we see the planet Krypton in a non-exploding state.

[image]

Comment: "Extra! Extra! Read all about it! Superman In Danger!"  -- Lois wrote the story about the Kryptonite Meteor in the Daily Planet despite promising to keep it a secret to Clark. http://www.supermanhomepage.com/radio/radio.php?topic=radio-reviews/101045-scarletwidow